# How to access class variables from a module in another module (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycharm

```
project_name
   |
    package1
       |__init__.py
       |
        package2
           |__init__.py
           |
            driver.py
           |
            package3
               |__init__.py
               |
                test.py
```

I have tried this many times but i really don't understand what mistake I'm doing here.
Need your guidance here. I am learning python, please help me.
Created project as defined above (structure).

**test.py :**  Defined `class Test` and defined variables here as shown below.

```
test.py

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
    
        self.val1 = "value1"
        self.val2 = "value2"
```

**driver.py:** This is the driver script, which I will be using for execution.

```
python /package1/package2/driver.py
               or
cd project_name/package1/package2/
python driver.py
```

**driver.py**

```
from package1.package2.package3.test import Test   # All these values are populated

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def fun1(self):
        print(Test.)   # I don't see any variables populating her after 'Test.'
```

In above snippet, when I import as `from package1.package2.package3.test import Test` all values are auto-populated.

When tried `print(Test.)`, it does not populate variables.
Am I doing it right way ? If any better way of importing modules, please help me to understand.

**Pycharm, Python 3.8, Windows 10**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get autocomplete because those variables

```
self.val1 = "value1"
self.val2 = "value2"
```

you want to access do not belong to the `Test` class. They instead belong to instances of the `Test` class, since they are only declared when an object is created (because the `__init__(self)` function is only called when creating an object)

Creating a `Test` object lets you access those variables

```
print(Test().val1)
```

will print "*value1*" as you would expect.
However you usually store the created object inside a variable

```
my_object = Test()
print(my_object.val1)
```

A class can also have variables that are shared among all of its instances (objects)

```
class Test:

    c = 3
    d = 4

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 2
```

in this example the variables `c` and `d` can be accessed using the class like this

```
print(Test.c)
```

and will print "*3*"

Class variables can also be accessed from its instances

```
object = Test()
print(object.c)  # --> 3
```

I hope you found this answer helpful. Have a nice day

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand. As you defined above in class Test, in what scenarios you define c,d and self.a,self.b ?

Comment: @Fresher `self.a` and `self.b` are usually better when they represent a feature of an object. For example an instance of a `Person` class should have a `self.name` and `self.age` features. On the other hand class variables are used when they should be the same among all instances (objects). For example `Person.legs_number` should be the same for every `Person` object you create, since humans should have the same number of legs. That said, class variables are used less often and I personally don't use them. Just think of whether using them would make more sense and, if not, stick with `self.a`